# Why a request doesn't work in laravel but it work in pgAdmin?

Tags: php, laravel

In my PHP code I have a request to get the data for a dropdown menu in my html. In pgAdmin I try this :

```sql
select distinct annee + 1 as annee from revisionrdt.rdt;
```

In PHP :

```php
$data = DB::table('previsionrdt.rdt')
    ->select ('annee')
    ->distinct ('annee + 1 as annee')
    ->from ('previsionrdt.rdt')
    ->get();
```

Normally this request return "2019" but in PHP the request return "2018" to me.

Comment: did you check that you have set any PHP constant (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_constants.asp) in you code?

Comment: The query in pgAdmin doesn't specify a table, where is it selecting from?

Comment: @CaddyDZ Sorry I forgot to write the specified table

Comment: @Raa I have no constant variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code generates another query:

```
DB::table('previsionrdt.rdt')
    ->select ('annee')
    ->distinct ('annee + 1 as annee')
    ->from ('previsionrdt.rdt')
    ->get();
```

->

```
select distinct `annee` from `previsionrdt`.`rdt`
```

Should be like this:

```
DB::table('previsionrdt.rdt')
    ->select(DB::raw('distinct annee + 1 as annee'))
    ->get();
```

->

```
select distinct annee + 1 as annee from `previsionrdt`.`rdt`
```

You could use `dump()` or `dd()` (dump and die) instead of `get()` to print and debug your queries.